# Is there any cumulative constraint propagation technique for dynamic programming?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, dynamic-programming

I have a problem with the following two properties:

- Overlapping Subproblems
- Optimal Substructure (an optimal solution can be constructed efficiently from optimal solutions of its subproblems)

However, I have a cumulative nonlinear (but convex) constraint. I have the following questions and asking for your guidance:

- Are model predictive control and dynamic programming optimization algorithms applicable to problems which have cumulative constraints?
- Is there any cumulative constraint propagation techniques for dynamic programming?